# Linux systray "UI"

Tags: python, linux, system-tray, xfce

got a cli(python). I'd like to add super light ui for it.
By "UI" is meant to pack it as systray item.

Some controls(widgets) to be used - check box, button
Plus, conditional formatting would be needed.

I'm thinking about using Tkinter (not decided completely)

Suppose the UI is done, how to pack it as sys tray item ?

In use, linux + xfce

ps. generally any thoughts on the subject welcome

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

XFCE is implemented in GTK and python has a good library to work with it
`PyGObject`, the official page of library is https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

I think this is the easiest way to create a systray item for a Python application.